# undefined local variable or method when calling category.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a Category model for my books model and already associated both with

```
has_many :books
```

and

```
belongs_to :category
```

I was also able to add a simple form dropdown list in my _form.html.haml and save book entries with categories associate however; whenever I try to show all categories in my index.html.haml file I get an Action Controller: Exception caught error:

"undefined local variable or method `categroy' for #<#:0x39040f8>"

this is the code I'm using:

```
- Category.all.each do |category|
  =link_to category.name, books_path(category: categroy.name)
```

**EDIT**

I also added an index filter in my books_controller.rb

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @book = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @book =Book.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

without the link_to code, the index filter works when I try to manually type it in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/books?category=Elementary
```

It looks like the category model works but I'm not sure why it isn't allowing me to call category.name

I just started rails 2 weeks ago and would really appreciate any assistance from the community. Please let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: The error says it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote `categroy`, but the name of variable is `category` :)

should be
`=link_to category.name, books_path(category: category.name)`